# How to use WMIC to connect to remote machine and output netstat to a file?

Tags: rpc, wmi

I'm trying to issue the following command remotely:

netstat -ano > C:\output.txt

but cannot figure out how to do that with WMIC! Any idea?

I've got:

```
process call create netstat.exe
```

working but I cannot figure out how to pass the -ANO nor the output. Help please :)

Answer (score 2):

When issuing remote commands, quote the entire string to execute, like:

```
wmic /node:remote_computer process call create "netstat.exe -ano > C:\output.txt"
```

Comment: You probably need to add a `/output:stdout` because it does not do this by default if *you want the file on the remote computer* (that is ambiguous in your question), or it will be a useless output file.  It took me a long time with wmic to figure that out.

Comment: To add to the question, id like the output to be redirected to the remote machine (the issuer). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
wmic /node:remote_computer process call create "cmd /c \"pushd \\remote_server\c$ && netstat -nao > n.txt && popd\""
```

Comment: This answer is not very useful without an explanation of what it is doing.

Answer (score -1):

Another option to get the list of open connections on a computer is to use PowerShell and/or WMI: https://www.action1.com/kb/list_of_open_tcp_ip_connections_on_remote_computer.html

With PowerShell, for example, you can filter or sort the results or even query multiple computers at the same time:

`Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like “Windows 10*”} | ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_NetTCPConnection -Computer $_.Name}`

Comment: Please a least give one example in your answer as text instead of just an URL.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue.
 And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).